# Sending more than one Buffer in a single response with Node

Tags: node.js, fetch, buffer

I am creating two buffers from images and would like to send them in a single response to the client from a Node server.

Server:

```js
    const response1 = await fetch(imageUrls[0]);
    const response2 = await fetch(imageUrls[1]);
    const arrayBuffer1 = await response1.arrayBuffer();
    const arrayBuffer2 = await response2.arrayBuffer();

    const buffer1 = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer1, "base64");
    const buffer2 = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer2, "base64");

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        first: buffer1,
        second: buffer2,
      })
    );
```

Client:

```js
  fetch(endpoint + new URLSearchParams(paramsObj), {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      const { first, second } = JSON.parse(response.body);
      obv.blob().then((blob) => download(blob));
      rev.blob().then((blob) => download(blob));
    })
```

The issue is that `response.body` is still a ReadableStream and not a parseable string as I would expect to get with `JSON.stringify`.

I also tried to send a combined response with two `res.write()`s but was only getting the first buffer.

The following works if I only send 1 buffer from the server with `res.send(buffer1)`:

```js
    .then((response) => {
      response.blob().then((blob) => download(blob));
    })
```

Comment: JSON does not have a way of expressing the Buffer object.  That's not a base type that JSON supports.  So, you probably need to encode or convert the Buffer into something that JSON does know how to represent (an array of numbers or an encoded string).  Or, you need to send it as a different content-type than application/json.

Comment: What are you intending on doing with the fetched images? Display them in an `<img>`? Draw them to a Canvas? Download them?

Comment: Yes download them, and getting the data from the server prevents any CORS issues (origin domain is not under my control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to send the buffers as JSON, you should consider converting them to Base64 strings and then sending a JSON object in the response just like you are already doing. I do not think the JSON format supports Buffers.

```
const response1 = await fetch(imageUrls[0]);
const response2 = await fetch(imageUrls[1]);

const buffer1 = convertBufferToBase64(response1);
const buffer2 = convertBufferToBase64(response2);

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
res.send(
  JSON.stringify({
    first: buffer1,
    second: buffer2,
  })
);
```

An alternative would be to stream the buffer on the response, in which case you would have to set the Content-Type header to some binary format like application/octet-stream or so.

```
const response1 = await fetch(imageUrls[0]);
const arrayBuffer1 = await response1.arrayBuffer();

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
res.send(
  arrayBuffer1
);
```

Personally, I would just redirect the client to fetch the image by itself by setting the location header and status code in the response like so.

```
const imageUrls = ["blah", "hablo"];
res.setHeader("Location", imageUrls[0]);
res.status(301); //may also use 302 | 303 | 307 | 308
res.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well with the following code on the client:

```.then((response) => response.json()).then((parsed) => { const { first, second } = parsed; downloadBase64File(first); downloadBase64File(second); });```